# How to create shaking randomly images

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I wanted to make a shaking image in a imageView in Appcelerator TItanium

What I would like to do is to randomly change the top position and the left position of an imageView, to do like a shaking image.

```
OriginalImageLeft = image.left;
OriginalImageTop = image.top;

if (Math.random() > 0.5){
    value = -1;
} else {
    value = 1;
} 

var viewAnimate = Ti.UI.createAnimation({
    duration: 2000,
    repeat:100,
    left: OriginalImageLeft + (Math.random() * 20 * value),
    top: OriginalImageTop + (Math.random() * 20 * value),
});

image.animate(viewAnimate)
```

But the code is not working, it calculates only one time the MathRandom() function so the shaking is not working.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function to calculate the position + doing the animation once. Then use the animation `complete` event to call that function again so it will calculate a new position + running the animation again. If you want to stop it just don't call the fuction again (e.g. add a counter/if-case around the function call).

*A short info why your code won't work:*
the `OriginalImageLeft + (Math.random() * 20 * value)` part is send to the native path once. So it will execute the Math.random() part in JS and send that number to the native App. The actual `repeat` part is executed with that calculated number.

Comment: OriginalImageLeft = image.left;
  OriginalImageTop = image.top;
  if (Math.random() > 0.5){
   value = -1;
  } else {
   value = 1;
  }

  function newPosition(){
      var viewAnimate = Ti.UI.createAnimation({
          duration: 2000,
   left:OriginalImageLeft + (Math.random() * 20 * value),
          top:OriginalImageTop + (Math.random() * 20 * value),
      });
      Image.animate(viewAnimate);
      viewAnimate.addEventListener('complete', function(){
    newPosition();
   });
  }

      newPosition();
`code` But it does the animation only once ?

Comment: works absolutly fine here http://migaweb.de/ti_shake.mp4